# JS: do-while loop infinitely loops over function when timeout is set

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop, do-while, prompt

i need a prompt window to let the user type in a number.
When setting the function (code below) once, everything works but this promt window should accure until a variable with an integer (starting from 200) reaches 0, so i thought a do while loop would do the trick. 
But when setting the do while loop the prompt window shows up immediately after typing in a number and does not change anything. 
I also changed the code until the loop got infinite and my brwoser crashed.
I know that the condition in the do while loop is always true (`machineFuel > 0 && height > 0`) because the variables `machineFuel and height` are greater than 0 but i dont know how to set it up correctly.

Here the relevant code (shortened)

```
var machineFuel = 200;
var height = 500;


setTimeout(round, 2000);

function round() {
    do {
       playerInput = input();
    } while (machineFuel > 0 && height > 0);
    calculate();
}

function input(fuel) {
    fuel = parseInt(prompt("Fuel", "A number from 0-200"));
    return fuel;
}

function calculate() {
    machineFuel = machineFuel - playerInput;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `calculate` after `input()` otherwise your `machineFuel` won't be updated and `while` will run forever.
Also the OP commented he needs the timeout after each prompt. So we remove `while` and call `setTimeout()` again:

```js
var machineFuel = 200;
var height = 500;


setTimeout(round, 2000);

function round() {
   playerInput = input();
   calculate();
   machineFuel > 0 && height > 0 && setTimeout(round, 2000);
}

function input(fuel) {
    fuel = parseInt(prompt("Fuel", "A number from 0-200"));
    return fuel;
}

function calculate() {
    machineFuel = machineFuel - playerInput;
}
```

The OP asked for a `while` option. For that we need to wrap `setTimeout` to a promise:

```js
var machineFuel = 200;
var height = 500;

round();

async function round() {

  do {
    
   await delay(2000);
    
   playerInput = input();
   calculate();
  
  } while (machineFuel > 0 && height > 0);

}

function delay(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

function input(fuel) {
    fuel = parseInt(prompt("Fuel", "A number from 0-200"));
    return fuel;
}

function calculate() {
    machineFuel = machineFuel - playerInput;
}
```

Comment: infinite loop is gone but still makes the prompt appear instantly and the typed in number has no affect on the original value (200)

Comment: but can your line of code also be written in a do-while loop? And if yes, how would it look like?

Comment: Thanks bro, this is yet to advanced for me but big thanks brother!